# Is there a standard component that can "save" a certain current or voltage and what is it's name?

Tags: components, active-components

What I am thinking about is something like this analog equivalent of a flipflop:

```
        ____________
1 °-----|---| A |---|-----° 2
3 °-----|----||-----|-----° 4
5 °-----|           |
        _____________
              |
             ___
              -

| A |: ampere meter
||: power source
```

The behaviour I'm looking for is that when a certain voltage is applied to pin 5 the current is measured between 1 and 2. This current should then be induced between 3 and 4.

Is it possible to do this in a purely non-digital manner?

Comment: You mean like a current mirror circuit? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror

Comment: Saving and copying aren't the same thing.

Comment: The current between 3 and 4 should not depend on the current between 1 and 2 if 5 is not high.

Comment: Hmm, I would not call that a flip-flop. A flip-flop has **two** output states. Yours has many possible output states, that immediately does not make it a flip-flop anymore. You will have to 1) provide more context how this is going to be used 2) provide more detailed electrical specifications. 3) coming up with a solution makes it a design job and that's not what we're here for. Some of us can be hired for hard cash though.

Comment: Smells of an XY problem.

Comment: This is mainly a question that came up in my mind when I thought about how one could implement analog neural networks. I have no real background in electrical engineering and I asked this question out of pure curiosity.

Comment: Which means that "Such a thing doesn't exist" is a perfectly valid answer for me :)

Comment: *I have no real background in electrical engineering* Yeah, that was clear to us from the way that you ask the question. It is simply too vague and leaves too many unknowns.

Comment: Given the time I can design 10 devices that fit what you describe yet none of those would be usable in your application. So no, it probably does not exist but is can probably be designed. But the environment it is going to be used in is an important factor. Also cost, accuracy, speed etc...

Comment: Analog neural networks can be made using electronics but it is usually much easier to design a digital implementation which behaves as if it is an analog network. Instead of actual voltages and currents **numbers** are processed which **represent** these voltages and currents. That way you can think up what you want, program it in an emulator (software) or FPGA and see if it works. Much easier than analog for this application in my opinion.

Comment: Sounds like a sample and hold amplifier - http://www.analog.com/en/products/amplifiers/specialty-amplifiers/sampletrack-hold-amplifiers/ad783.html#product-overview

Comment: There exist superconducting Josephson Junction devices that might be made to work sort of like that, but superconducting materials generally require somewhat costly and exotic cryogenic cooling systems... in that field, "high temperature" means you only need liquid nitrogen coolant. None of that works at room temp. A more practical solution would be to use voltage-based signals instead of current-based signals, then you could use a sample-and-hold like HandyHowie suggests. Might even be able to implement a voltage-based sample/hold using a low RDSon switch with a low dissipation capacitor.

Comment: The title probably asks for a Sample and Hold circuit, as others have noted (which can "save" a voltage on demand). But the body asks for something quite different (possibly a current mirror) and it's not clear what...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest device to your description that I can think of is a sample and hold amplifier.  For example - http://www.analog.com/en/products/amplifiers/specialty-amplifiers/sampletrack-hold-amplifiers/ad783.html#product-overview